# React Native Sort array by date

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to sort results from a prop by date & time. Not sure how to do this.

```
props.data.map((r) => {
      console.log(r);
    });
```

array example

```
{
    "date": "2021-07-17",
    "time": "3:00",
    "title": "First Title",
    "description": "Testing"
}, {
    "date": "2021-07-17",
    "time": "3:00",
    "title": "Second Title",
    "description": "Testing"
}
```

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053/9868549 I literally typed your title in google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert date into timestamp then compare timestamp to sort them using `sort` array method.

More about sort method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
const data = [
{
    "date": "2021-07-17",
    "time": "3:00",
    "title": "First Title",
    "description": "Testing"
}, {
    "date": "2021-07-18",
    "time": "3:00",
    "title": "Second Title",
    "description": "Testing"
},
{
    "date": "2021-07-18",
    "time": "2:59",
    "title": "Second Title",
    "description": "Testing"
 }
]

const sorted = data.sort((a,b)=>{
  const dateA = new Date(`${a.date} ${a.time}`).valueOf();
  const dateB = new Date(`${b.date} ${b.time}`).valueOf();
  if(dateA > dateB){
    return 1; // return -1 here for DESC order
  }
  return -1 // return 1 here for DESC Order
});
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Works perfect. Is there a way to do this with "time"

Comment: it works for combination of both `date` and `time` properties. do you mean sort only by `time` value?

Comment: Yes sort only by time

Comment: what if time is same but date is different?

Comment: In this case the date will always be the same

Comment: Ok then you can use the above code. it will work fine.